# How can I generate a random number after typing one to compare?

Tags: excel, vba, random

I need to create a generator, that compares your "typed" number with a random one, generated by Excel.

If you guessed correctly, you get a positive message, if not - a negative one.

The problem is, that after guessing your number, the one displayed in the field for Excel does not change.

The line

```
Range("G23").Value = "=RANDBETWEEN(1,36)"
```

does not change the cell value.

Is there any way to connect cells G22 and G23, so that when I write a number between 1 and 36 in G22, G23 generates a random number?

Comment: The solution is in using Worksheet_Change event. Suggest researching and testing using that.

Comment: On a worksheet change event, you can simply check if the target address is G22 and if so, then generate a random number just using `Range("G23") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Randbetween(1,36)`. Then simply compare if G22 = G23 and if so use a `Msgbox`

Comment: Thank you all! I got to solve the problem with your help!

Answer (score 0):

The code below expects two **named ranges**:

- PlayersNumber (G22)
- RandomNumber (G23)

Furthermore I put the two values for min and max as const at the top of the module - then it is much easier to change the range if necessary.

The Worksheet_Change event checks first for a cell with a name, then the name is checked. If "PlayersNumber" has changed, the value is checked (numeric plus within min-max-range) and then the random number gets updated by random value. If the PlayersNumber does not fit the conditions RandomNumber will be reset and PlayersNumbers cell selected.

The code has to be pasted into the worksheet module of G22/PlayersNumber

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Const minValue As Long = 1
Private Const maxValue As Long = 36

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim c As Range: Set c = Target.Cells(1, 1)  'only handle first changed cell

Dim cName As String
If tryGetName(c, cName) = False Then Exit Sub   'a cell without name, therefore we can exit the sub

If cName Like "*PlayersNumber" Then
    If isOKPlayersNumber(c.Value2) = True Then
        updateRandomNumber
    Else
        c.Select
        resetRandomNumber
    End If
End If

End Sub

Private Function isOKPlayersNumber(value As Variant) As Boolean
Dim strMessage As String
strMessage = "Please enter a number between 1 and 36"

Dim fShowMessage As Boolean
If Not IsNumeric(value) Then
    fShowMessage = True
ElseIf value < minValue Or value > maxValue Then
    fShowMessage = True
End If

If fShowMessage = True Then
    MsgBox strMessage, vbCritical
Else
    isOKPlayersNumber = True
End If
        
End Function

Private Sub updateRandomNumber()
Application.EnableEvents = False    'to avoid another workshet_change event
Me.Range("RandomNumber") = getRandomNumber(minValue, maxValue)
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub resetRandomNumber()
Application.EnableEvents = False    'to avoid another workshet_change event
Me.Range("RandomNumber").ClearContents
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub


'These functions could go as public functions in a normal module as well.
'Then you can re-use them for other scenarios
Private Function getRandomNumber(minValue As Long, maxValue As Long) As Long
Randomize
getRandomNumber = CLng(2 + Rnd * (maxValue - minValue + 1))
End Function

Private Function tryGetName(c As Range, ByRef cName As String) As String
On Error Resume Next
cName = c.Name.Name
If Err = 0 Then tryGetName = True
On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```